# Windows media foundation use raw image to encode video

Tags: c++, directshow, rgb, screen-capture, ms-media-foundation

I'm working on a project that requires me to record webcam, microphone, and the screen.  I have webcam recording, [audio is a work in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917256/windows-media-foundation-recording-audio/12917612), and I stumbled across [CMonitor wrapper](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/article.php/c18347/C-Programming-Easy-Screen-Capture-Using-MFCATL.htm) (which I did some minor modifications to) to grab RGB images of the desktop on a specified monitor (if there are multiple monitors).

How do I go about pushing my raw RGB frames into windows media foundation to encode into a video file?  My current video encoding is using a slightly modified version of [this msdn sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663604(v=vs.85).aspx), if that's easier to modify than it is to write a new class handler.

Or, perhaps there is some sort of media foundation route to recording the screen that I don't know of (which is possible, I'm not that great of a win32 programmer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found PushSource in the Windows SDK samples, which does this.

Comment: It is [from DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not Media Foundation, right?

Comment: Yeah, I scrapped the media foundation stuff, probably should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Desktop Duplication API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for capture desktop. Media Foundation provides two solution for encoding, MF Sink Writer for simple encoding, Media Session for a more flexible control of the media pipeline. Read this [overview page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485861) first.