# IAMVideoProcAmp GetRange only works after delay (C++)?

Tags: c++, windows, video-capture, ms-media-foundation

I have an issue trying to control camera parameters. Here is the function to set brightness parameter (I am extending the code from [Windows Media Foundation recording audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917256/windows-media-foundation-recording-audio)) :

```
HRESULT deviceInput::SetupCamera(UINT32 deviceID) {
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
IMFActivate* device = this->getDevice(deviceID);
if (device == NULL)
    return E_FAIL;
IMFMediaSource* pCameraSource = NULL;
HRESULT hr = (m_devices[deviceID])->ActivateObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pCameraSource));
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    wcout << "Could not activate object" << endl;
    return hr;
}
IAMVideoProcAmp* spVideo = NULL;
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(IMFMediaSource) , NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IAMVideoProcAmp),
                      reinterpret_cast<void**>(&spVideo));  
hr = pCameraSource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&spVideo));
if(FAILED(hr)) {
    wcout << "Could not get interface" << endl;
    return hr;
}
if(spVideo) {
    wcout << "Getting brightness" << endl;
    long Min, Max, step, def, control;
    Sleep(100); // if I remove this - will get "Element not found error"
    hr = spVideo->GetRange(VideoProcAmp_Brightness, &Min, &Max, &step, &def, &control);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        wcout << "Brightness. Min = " << Min <<", max = " << Max << endl;
    else {
        _com_error err(hr);
        LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
        wcout << "Failed: " << errMsg << endl;
    }
}
CoUninitialize();
return hr;
}
```

It seems I need to insert a pause before calling GetRange() method, otherwise I am getting "Element not found" error. QueryInterface works correctly, since I am checking HRESULT value, and spVideo gets populated regardless of the delay. Does anyone know how to get this to work without inserting arbitrary delays?

Comment: I suppose you need to start video capture from this source and change parameters on active device. This should ensure the backstage stuff is properly initialized.

Answer (score 1):

you described well known problem. The fact is that after execution of activating system needs time for initializing driver for camera. It needs time. If you really want to remove `Sleep` function then you should call camera properties via `DeviceIoControl`
On MSDN [USB Video Class Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff568660(v=vs.85).aspx) you find the next text "Call KsSynchronousDeviceControl or DeviceIoControl to make property requests from a user-mode component. DeviceIoControl is documented in the Microsoft Windows SDK documentation."
By the way, for using of `DeviceIoControl` it DOES NOT NEED activate MediaSource. `DeviceIoControl` function needs only symbolicLink of camera. However, writing code for direct working with driver can be very difficult (I wrote it in one C++ class).

Comment: Evgeny, thanks for the answer. So there is no way to check if the driver is ready from within MediaFoundation class (some kind of blocking call maybe?).

Comment: No. There is no way for working with camera properties via `MediaFoundation`. Only via `IAMVideoProcAmp` DirectShow or `DeviceIoControl`. Camera is a hardware device - it means that for working with it you need use the same code as for working with any device on Windows (for example hard disk) - `DeviceIoControl`.