# How to write an avi file with DirectShow

Tags: c++, winapi, video, directshow

I'm trying to write an avi video file based on the streaming of my Decklink SDI card, after looking in the internet and here I wrote this code by my problem is that the program  doesn't write the file here 's the code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <DShow.h>
#include <iostream>


 int main(void)
{
IGraphBuilder* pGraph = NULL;
ICaptureGraphBuilder2* pBuild = NULL;
IMediaControl* pControl = NULL;

ICreateDevEnum* pDevEnum = NULL;
IEnumMoniker* pEnum = NULL;
IMoniker *pMoniker = NULL;
IMoniker* goodMoniker = NULL;
IBaseFilter* pCap;
HRESULT hr;

//Initialize pGraph
hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
   hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **) &pGraph);
if(FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("ERROR - Could not initialize COM library");
    return 1;
}

//Initialize pBuild


 hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2, (void**) &pBuild);
if(FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("ERROR - Could not create the Filter Graph Manager.");
    return 2;
}
pBuild->SetFiltergraph(pGraph);



hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICreateDevEnum, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pDevEnum));
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pDevEnum->CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, &pEnum, 0);
}


HWND hList;

while(pEnum->Next(1, &pMoniker, NULL) == S_OK)
{
    IPropertyBag* pPropBag;
    hr = pMoniker->BindToStorage(0, 0, IID_IPropertyBag, (void**)(&pPropBag));
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        pMoniker->Release();
        continue;
    }

    VARIANT varName;
    VariantInit(&varName);
    hr = pPropBag->Read(L"Description", &varName, 0);
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        hr = pPropBag->Read(L"FriendlyName", &varName, 0);
    }
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
           std::cout<<(char)*(varName.bstrVal + i);
        }

        char yn;
        std::cin>>yn;

        if(yn=='Y')
        {
            std::cout<<"SUCCESSFUL"<<std::endl;
            goodMoniker = pMoniker;
            VariantClear(&varName);
        }
    }
    pPropBag->Release();
    if(pMoniker != goodMoniker)
    {
        pMoniker->Release();
    }
}


hr = goodMoniker->BindToObject(0, 0, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)(&pCap));

if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pGraph->AddFilter(pCap, L"Capture Filter");

}

IBaseFilter *pMux = NULL;

//  hr = pBuild->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_PREVIEW, &MEDIATYPE_Video, pCap, NULL, NULL);

hr = pBuild->SetOutputFileName(
&MEDIASUBTYPE_Avi,  // Specifies AVI for the target file.
L"C:\\stuff.avi", // File name.
&pCap,              // Receives a pointer to the mux.
NULL);              // (Optional) Receives a pointer to the file sink.

hr =pBuild->RenderStream(
&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, // Pin category.
&MEDIATYPE_Video,      // Media type.
pCap,                  // Capture filter.
NULL,                  // Intermediate filter (optional).
pMux);                 // Mux or file sink filter.  


hr = pCap->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl,(void**) pControl);

printf("START ");
hr = pControl->Run();

Sleep(100000);
hr = pControl->Stop();
CoUninitialize();


pGraph->Release();
pBuild->Release();
pCap->Release();
```

}

here is the error message that I get when I try to debbug it :

```
  Unhandled exception at 0x776015de in STREAMMMMM.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

the program crashes in this line :

```
 r = pCap->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl,(void**) pControl);
```

Comment: Don't write files to the c:\ root directory, UAC forbids write access.  Use the AmCap sample for inspiration.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373424%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There are tens, if not hundreds, of examples on how to write into AVI with DirectShow on Internet.

This particular code snippet does not even start writing. It only prepares the pipeline and you are not even doing `IMediaControl::Run`, what you are supposed to do. Further on, you should wait until you wrote enough, and then stop recording and only then release the interface pointers.

Have a look at this Q: [Using a DirectShow filter without registering it, via a private CoCreateInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191996/using-a-directshow-filter-without-registering-it-via-a-private-cocreateinstance) on what you are missing to start actual capture and writing (`IMediaControl::Run` and `Sleep` in particular).

Comment: I Just want to record 10 s from my device

Comment: I added a link to another question for you to look at.

Comment: @ Roman thanks for your help i edited the code based on the other Question but it still don't work( pl,ease see my edited Question

Comment: You are supposed to do some debugging and get error codes whatsoever. Something you might also want to look at is SDK from Blackmagic. It is public download and has sample code for DirectShow projects, see `\Blackmagic DeckLink SDK 9.5\Win\Samples` there. Pre-built executables are also there. Apart from already mentioned, there might be other reasons to not record video, such as setting incorrect capture format on Decklink board.

Comment: My code doesn't work for both a webcam and the Decklink SDI card .

Comment: and the Blackmagic example is too complicated to understand (at the less for me) and they are use the codecs and all I want is to get the video a writing it . thanks so again for you help

Comment: I don't think you provided the correct failure line, but this line is definitely having an issue. It should have been like this: `pGraph->QueryInterface(..., IID_IMediaControl`, that is `pGraph`, and not `pCap`.

Comment: I did but and I changed my code I just don't understand why it's so complicated to grabbe a video using Direchtshow I did it with opencv and it was fine the quality  is my problem